# Concatenação de duas listas encadeadas em C

Tags: c

Dado o **TAD LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD**, preciso implementar uma operação que recebe duas listas e retorna uma lista resultante da concatenação das mesmas, e que não pode ter elementos com mesmo valor.

Aqui o TAD:

```
typedef struct nodo
{
    int inf;
    struct nodo * next;
}NODO;
typedef NODO * LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD;
```

Ele é encadeado, ordenado de forma crescente e tem um nó cabeçalho (o nó é um NODO também, mas o campo inf dele é o número de elementos da lista, e o next dele é o primeiro elemento).

A operação:

```
LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD concatenar (LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD l1, LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD l2)
```

Operação de inserir:

```
void ins (LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD l, int val)
{
    NODO *novo, *aux;
    novo=(NODO *)malloc(sizeof(NODO));
if (!novo)
{
    printf ("erro! memoria insuficiente");
    exit(2);
}

for (aux=l; aux->next!=NULL && val>(aux->next)->inf; aux=aux->next);
novo->inf = val;
novo->next = aux->next;
aux->next = novo;
l->inf++;
}
```

Não consigo fazer de jeito nenhum, se alguém me ajudar ficarei muito agradecido ^^

Comment: O que você já tentou? Qual problema específico você está tendo? Com mais informação fica possível ajudar sem sair fazendo o dever de casa todo pra você. :)

Comment: Voltando ao assunto, dado que as listas estão ordenadas, fiquei com a impressão que a operação que você quer implementar tá mais prum "merge" do que para uma concatenação. E devo confessar que é bem esquisito esse esquema de armazenar o tamanho da lista no primeiro elemento.

Comment: meu problema é que não sabia o que fazer para que a lista não tivesse elementos repetidos

Comment: esse esquema de armazenar o tamanho é pra não precisar percorrer a lista inteira pra descobrir o número de elementos

Comment: A razão de eu achar esquisito é que, ao contrário de vetores, listas ligadas não precisam saber seu próprio tamanho para para fazer a maioria das coisas. E armazenando o número de elementos dentro da própria lista fica super fácil de você fazer um erro e tratar o número de elementos como se ele próprio fosse um elemento. Uma maneira de amenizar esse problema seria armazenar os metadados em um segundo tipo de dados ao invés de botar eles "in-band".

Comment: Pra operações de inserção, consulta e remoção eu uso para saber se a posição em que o usuário quer inserir, consultar ou remover é válida.

Comment: Se a lista está ordenada, não faz sentido o usuário passar uma posição. E mesmo se fizesse, ficar inserindo coisas no meio de uma lista ligada não é eficiente porque você tem que ficar percorrendo a lista toda hora.

Comment: Sim, numa lista ordenada não faz sentido mesmo. O professor só quis complicar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se as listas pudessem ter valores repetidos, bastaria varrer uma lista e depois a outra, inserindo os elementos na lista nova. Como **não** pode ter elementos repetidos, você varre uma das listas e a cada elemento varre a outra lista completamente, verificando se há repetição. Se houver, **pula** para o próximo elemento da primeira lista, sem inseri-lo, até acabar a lista. Uma vez acabada, passa-se a varrer a segunda lista, inserindo **todos** os elementos dela na lista nova.

Vou considerar o seguinte protótipo para criação de listas:

```
LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD criar();
```

O código a seguir é uma tentativa de resolução do exercício:

```
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD concatenar(LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD l1, LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD l2)
{
    LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD nova;
    LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD v;
    LISTA_ENC_NC_ORD w;
    int pode_inserir;

    // criando a lista nova que sera retornada
    nova = criar();

    // laco para varrer a primeira lista
    for (v = l1; v != NULL; v = v->next)
    {
        pode_inserir = TRUE;

        // varrendo a segunda lista em busca de elementos comuns
        for (w = l2; w != NULL; w = w->next)
        {
            if (v->inf == w->inf)
            {
                // nao pode inserir
                pode_inserir = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (pode_inserir)
        {
            ins(nova, v->inf);
        }
    }

    // laco para varrer a segunda lista,
    // inserindo todos os elementos da lista 2 na lista nova
    for (w = l2; w != NULL; w = w->next)
    {
        ins(nova, w->inf);
    }

    // fim de operacao, retorna o valor desejado
    return nova;
}
```

Comment: nesse caso os elementos da lista 1 não estão sendo inseridos várias vezes?

Comment: verdade! vou corrigir

Comment: poxa cara, valeu mesmo xD não sabia o que fazer com os valores repetidos